# Quantidade de casas decimais

Tags: javascript, soma

Estou fazendo a soma de um carrinho de compras com javascript porém quando o número não é exato me retorna muitas casas decimais.

para resolver isso eu usei o toFixed(2). porém agora quando dá um número exato, ele retorna com duas casas decimais a mais com 0 e não passa no teste pois o teste espera que quando for inteiro retorne apenas o valor.

````
const sum = priceItem.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
sumPlace.innerText = sum.toFixed(2);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vai conseguir esse comportamento com uma função só, até porque o normal é querer um número fixo de casas decimais mesmo para valores inteiros (tipo um preço de 5 reais é expresso como R$ 5,00).

Teria de tratar você mesmo esta exceção, algo no estilo

```
if (sum === Math.floor(sum) {
    sumPlace.innerText = sum.toFixed(0);
} else {
    sumPlace.innerText = sum.toFixed(2);
}
```